# Plotting difference between two images with matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot the difference between two 1000x1000 images that I've tinkered with. A MWE would be as follows (where the top-right and bottom-left would be these images):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
import seaborn as sns
import numpy

sns.set(style='dark')

imagen2 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
imagen2.suptitle('StackOverflow Matplotlib colorbar demo')

dat = numpy.random.randn(1000, 1000)
top_left = plt.subplot(221)
top_left.imshow(dat)

top_right = plt.subplot(222, sharex=top_left, sharey=top_left)
top_right.imshow(dat)

bottom_left = plt.subplot(223, sharex=top_left, sharey=top_left)
bottom_left.imshow(dat)

bottom_right = plt.subplot(224, sharex=top_left, sharey=top_left)
# problem_plot = bottom_right.imshow(dat)
# plt.colorbar(problem_plot, fraction=0.045, pad=0.04)
problem_plot = sns.heatmap(dat)
problem_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(200))
problem_plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.ScalarFormatter())
problem_plot.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(200))
problem_plot.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.ScalarFormatter())

plt.tight_layout(rect=(0, 0, 1, 0.95))

plt.show()
```

[image: MWE illustrating sns.heatmap usage]

matplotlib's `imshow` is easy to save as PDF (albeit there are some alignment and size issues with the colorbar).
However, seaborn's `heatmap` solves this issue at the expense of a vector-heavy PDF: 6.2MB vs 3.7MB, after compression with `ps2pdf14 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress`.

Is there any other *efficient* way to plot this while preserving seaborn's aesthetical advantages?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you like about the bottom right plot. Is it the colorbar? The rotated x-axis labels?

Comment: To me it is not clear why you would suddenly use a seaborn plot only for the last subplot? It seems if you just use the same imshow as for the other three plots the file size problem does not occur. So that would be the solution here, wouldn't it?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin - if I plot it with `imshow`, I have to align and resize the colorbar manually (see the commented lines in the example), and it still isn't perfect.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - yes, I could use `imshow`, but I wanted to ask the community if there were other possibilities.

Comment: Yes there are always "other possibilities". But for what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do is to have a heatmap which wouldn't render each cell as an individual vector object. i.e. I would like the heatmap to be rasterized, just like `imshow` does with the array.

[seaborn's heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) uses [matplotlib's pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) behind the scenes (this is tucked in a corner of its docs). It has an optional Bool parameter, `rasterized`, which does exactly what I wanted.

I edited the `heatmap` call to look like this:

```
problem_plot = sns.heatmap(dat, rasterized=True)
```

### Performance

Measured with `time caffeinate python stackoverflow.py`, Python 3.6.5 (from Homebrew), MacOS Sierra 10.12.6.

matplotlib's `imshow`: 2.4MB pdf uncompressed, 1.1MB after compression.

```
real    0m2,089s
user    0m1,797s
sys     0m0,211s
```

seaborn's `heatmap` w/o `rasterized`: 23.8MB pdf uncompressed, 7.5MB after compression. And it still takes a lot to load (try doing it inside a pdf.js viewer to see it render *each cell of the heatmap*).

```
real    4m36,585s
user    4m27,727s
sys     0m3,512s
```

seaborn's `heatmap` w/`rasterized`: 2.5MB pdf uncompressed, 1.2MB after compression (roughly the same as with `imshow`).

```
real    0m3,306s
user    0m2,932s
sys     0m0,313s
```